# Angular css style flex item vertically top

Tags: css, angular

I am not expert in css styling. Can anyone help with the following to vertically align a text top.

I have the following in my angular template:

```
                    <div class="validation-error-section">
                        <i class="icon-md error-rd"></i>
                        <t-error [Text]="ERROR_MSG_UPLOAD_FAILED"></t-error>
                    </div>
```

and the style

```
.validation-error-section {
  display:flex; 
  flex-direction: row; 
  align-items: flex-start;
}
```

I want the text in  to display vertically top to align with the image. but it looks like below:
[image]

Can anyone help how to align the text 'The import of your file has faile...' vertically align to top ?

Comment: maybe your `<t-error` container has `height: 100%` similar with `display:block` ?

Comment: check the default margin or reduce the line-height

Comment: there is no margin or height

Answer (score 0):

Just align your items in the center of your message.

```css
.message {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  align-items: center;
}
.icon {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: #a33;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class='message'>
  <div class='icon'></div>
  <div class='text'>The import of your file has failed. Please try again.</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Switch from `align-items: flex-start;` to `align-items: start;`

If that is not enough then add also `align-self: start;'`

Check [Flex alignment documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Aligning_Items_in_a_Flex_Container#properties_that_control_alignment). You are interested on alignment for Cross Axis